# sql function to check if either value exists in either column of a table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, function

I'm new at this and having a little hard time with this sql function.
I'm trying to create a function in sql but its not working, which accepts a parameters of @A int and @B int
returns a data type of "bit". Trying to check if  @A int or @B int exists in a table columns C and D. If exists 
returns a value of 1 otherwise 0

here is my code

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_exist(
@A int, @B int
)
RETURNS bit
as
begin

Declare @year int
    select @year as [year]
    case [YEAR] when @A in (C or D)
    or @B in (C and D)
    then 1 else 0
    from dbo.mytable
    return @year 

end
```

Comment: You say "exists" in columns C and D but looking at your code you check that the value is between C and D

Comment: I changed to in and that is not working either

Comment: You have `in (C or D)` and then `in (C and D)`, neither of which is valid `IN` syntax.

Comment: how can I perform this check, can I use If statements?

Comment: can you please give me an example in a code

Comment: it is a bad practice to use a reserved word like "year" as a column name. I would recommend you use something more descriptive and unique, like 'BirthYear', 'TaxYear', etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at your code example I think you want something like this:

```
DECLARE @value AS BIT
IF EXISTS(
   SELECT NULL
   FROM dbo.mytable
   WHERE (@A = C OR @A = D) OR (@B = C OR @B = D)
) 
   SET @value = CAST(1 As bit)
ELSE 
   SET @value = CAST(0 As bit)

RETURN @value
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, but it still won't work, gives me all the following errors: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_exists, Line 30
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_exists, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'.
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_exists, Line 36
Must declare the scalar variable "@value".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 1, Procedure fn_exists, Line 38
Must declare the scalar variable "@value".
Msg 137, Level 15, State 2, Procedure fn_exists, Line 40
Must declare the scalar variable "@value".

Comment: The sql will not take the case outside of select

Comment: @user3347312 ok, should have been an `If` and not a `case`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Declare @value as bit

select @value =
case
    when exists(
      select 1
      from dbo.mytable
      where (@A = C OR @A = D) OR (@B = C OR @B = D)
    )
    then 1 else 0
end

return @value
```